# How do I get the Apache Tomcat System Icons on another account?

Tags: notification-area, tomcat

I installed 2 separate instances of Apache Tomcat 7 under my user profile account.

This gives me the apache status as a system icon.
[image]  [image]

If I log off and log in as the local administrator account, I cannot see these icons.

**How can I have these icons visible for both accounts?**

Answer (score 2):

I suppose both Apache and Tomcat are still running when you log into the admin account?! And you want to stop and start either or both from both accounts?

Go to the services from the control panel. Then look for the Tomcat service. Restart it from there.

Update:

The tray icons are not the services themselves. You can kill the tray icons without killing tomcat or apache. They are just launcher apps which launch a program that starts or stops that service.

Kill the tomcat icon in the tray. Check that tomcat is still running. Then start it again via the start menu (monitor tomcat). It should appear again. Then do the same in the other account. If this works, it should work for apache as well. If you can do it manually, you'll now have to put those two launcher apps in the startup menu (if that still exists in W7 and I believe there is another tool for these startup programs).

Comment: i understand this workaround, but my Q is if I can retain those icons between user accounts.

Comment: See my update!!